# node.js: Cannot find module 'ico'

Tags: node.js, express, favicon

My website (running on the express framework) suddenly started complaining that it needed a favicon. Upon adding a favicon.ico, it now gives me this error every time someone tries to view a page.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ico'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
...
```

Comment: Since you've solved the problem yourself, please close the question; for instance, add an answer yourself and accept that answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation... I can add an answer in 8 hours and accept it in something like 24

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolved; I have

```
app.all('/:action', function(req, res){
```

in my app.js, and it was trying to interpret the favicon.ico as a page.

Comment: I'm having the same issue any route (including .ico) with a period it says `Cannot find module`, so if i go to `/index.html` it says  `Cannot find module .html` how do I debug which route / middleware is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a 'GET' handler for '/favico.ico' ;

```
app.get('/favico.ico' , function(req , res){/*code*/});
```

you could just add it there to silence the error or you could respond with an actual img uri .

Answer (score 0):

some more information about the error would be helpful or some code examples.

just to make sure; you will have to add the path in which the .ico lies to a static route for express like so;

```
app.use("/mypathwhereicolies", express.static(__dirname+'/mypathwhereicolies'));
```